# An n-bit boolean function maps 0/1 strings to 0 or 1

Tags: combinatorics

$f: \{0,1\}^n -> \{0,1\}$

The function "depends on i" if there exists two $o/1$ strings (A and B) where A and B differ only at position i and $f(A) \not= f(B)$.

How many n-bit Boolean functions do not depend on i?

I have no clue how to start this one. If someone could explain me through the logic of it, I would be extremely grateful, and maybe I could figure out a similar problem. Thank you.

Comment: Can you start by determining how many $n$-bit Boolean functions there are?

Comment: @MartianInvader How would I do that?

Comment: Well, what are the choices you make when defining an $n$-bit Boolean function?

Comment: Would the total number of functions be $2^{2^n}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $2^{2^{n - 1}}$ n-bit Boolean functions that do not depend on i.

When determining the number of possible string combinations, you don't need to consider the i-th bit so there are $2^{n - 1}$ possibilities. And there are still 2 outputs to think about so the number of n-bit Boolean functions is $2^{2^{n - 1}}$.

Thanks MartianInvader :)